# Number of Nodes in binary tree having only left child

Tags: algorithm

How to find Number of Nodes in binary tree having only left child?

```
LeftNode(root)
{
    if(root==NULL) 
        return 0;

    if(root->left!=null && root-right==null)
        return (1+LeftNode(root->left));

    return (LeftNode (root->left) + LeftNode (root->right))
}
```

Comment: your algo seems clear and ok. so what is the question ?

Comment: @YoungHobbit - the right child might have a left child

Comment: @cricket_007 I got it. I misunderstood at first. Thanks.

Comment: Your question has been edited and now your solution seems correct. Before edition, I gave you an answer that is fundamentally the same as yours

Answer (score 1):

I would do so (C++):

```
int leftNode(Node * root)
{
  if (root == nullptr)
    return 0;

  // c is 1 if root has a left child and has not a right one
  int c = root->left != nullptr and root->right == nullptr ? 1 : 0;

  return c + leftNode(root->left) + leftNode(root->right);
}
```

Comment: since when is "and" a keyword ?

Comment: @gen-y-s I really do not know since when, or whether it is official. What I really I can be sure is that works with gcc and clang compilers ... and I personally prefer this way because it is more expressive than the mere operator &&

Answer (score 0):

Since no specific language is required I am going to write my solutions in Swift

```
func nodesWithOnlyLeftChild(node:Node?) -> UInt {
    guard let node = node else { return 0 }
    let count: Uint = (node.left != nil && node.right == nil) ? 1 : 0
    return nodesWithOnlyLeftChild(node.left) + nodesWithOnlyLeftChild(node.right) + count
}
```

### Explaination

**1: The signature**

```
func nodesWithOnlyLeftChild(node:Node?) -> UInt
```

The function accepts a parameter of type `Node?`. This does mean the parameter can be a `Node` or `nil`.
The function does return an unsigned integer.

**2: Checking the parameter**

```
guard let node = node else { return 0 }
```

The first line verify that the input param is not `nil`. If it is not nil then the next line is executed, otherwise `0` is returned.

**3: Evaluating the current node**

```
let count: UInt = (node.left != nil && node.right == nil) ? 1 : 0
```

The constant `count` is created. It is populated with `1` if this node has only a left child. `0` otherwise.

**4: Recursive calls**

```
return nodesWithOnlyLeftChild(node.left) + nodesWithOnlyLeftChild(node.right) + count
```

The function does return the result of `nodesWithOnlyLeftChild` applied to the left child **+** `nodesWithOnlyLeftChild` applied to the right child **+** the constant `count`

### Considerations

The **time complexity** of this function is `O(n)` where `n` is the nodes in the three.

The **space complexity** is `O(1)`.
Infact although we can have max n recursive calls, the [Tail Recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) (supported by LLVM and other compilers) does use the same stack frame when some conditions are met.